# WHMCS the first year and the next year the price cycle

Tags: whmcs

How to add first year and next year price cycle like that,

First year my package price : £199, but next year would be £99.

How to set like that package in pricing on WHMCS

Answer (score 2):

You can add £100 as setup fee and £99 as the price for your package. So, the first invoice will be generated of £199 and from the next invoice, it will be £99.

Check the Pricing Tab from http://docs.whmcs.com/Products_and_Services#Products

Answer (score 1):

On **Product/Services** (Client Profile) there is `First Payment Amount` and `Recurring Amount`

Put `£199` at `First Payment Amount` and `£99` at `Recurring Amount` and **Save Changes**